# curl TLS handshake not successful

Tags: curl, tcp, centos8

I try to call several API Gateways from a virtual machine (centos) using curl.

```
 curl https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com -v
```

This works as expected except for one.

The curl call hangs after the ClientHello until the timeout. The ServerHello should come next, but nothing happens.

```
curl https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com -v
* connected to xxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com port 443
* ALPN, offering h2
* APLN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verfiy locations
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
* CAPath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1): 
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to xxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443
* Closing connection 0
```

At the TCP level, you can see that the ids for tcp_sync and tcp_ack do not match.

```
vm_client.48012 > api_gateway.https: Flags [S], seq 2805348193, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 919578686 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
api_gateway.https > vm_client.48012: Flags [S.], seq 1879651467, ack 2805348194, win 26847, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 88620492 ecr 919578686,nop,wscale 8], length 0
vm_client.48012 > api_gateway.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 919578721 ecr 88620492], length 0
vm_client.48012 > api_gateway.https: Flags [P.], seq 1:518, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 919578739 ecr 88620492], length 517
api_gateway.https > vm_client.48012: Flags [.], ack 518, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 88620506 ecr 919578739], length 0
api_gateway.https > vm_client.48012: Flags [P.], seq 4345:5332, ack 518, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 88620506 ecr 919578739], length 987
vm_client.48012 > api_gateway.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 244, options [nop,nop,TS val 919578776 ecr 88620506,nop,nop,sack 1 {4345:5332}], length 0

vm_client.48012 > api_gateway.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 244, options [nop,nop,TS val 919640456 ecr 88620506,nop,nop,sack 1 {4345:5332}], length 0
api_gateway.https > vm_client.48012: Flags [.], ack 518, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 88635940 ecr 919578776], length 0
vm_client.48012 > api_gateway.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 244, options [nop,nop,TS val 919701898 ecr 88620506,nop,nop,sack 1 {4345:5332}], length 0
api_gateway.https > vm_client.48012: Flags [.], ack 518, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 88651295 ecr 919578776], length 0
vm_client.48012 > api_gateway.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 244, options [nop,nop,TS val 919763339 ecr 88620506,nop,nop,sack 1 {4345:5332}], length 0
api_gateway.https > vm_client.48012: Flags [.], ack 518, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 88666654 ecr 919578776], length 0
vm_client.48012 > api_gateway.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 244, options [nop,nop,TS val 919824781 ecr 88620506,nop,nop,sack 1 {4345:5332}], length 0
api_gateway.https > vm_client.48012: Flags [.], ack 518, win 110, options [nop,nop,TS val 88682014 ecr 919578776], length 0
```

What is going wrong here and how could I get closer to the real problem? Do you have any ideas?
The firewall on the virtual machine is switched off.

Answer (score 0):

There was no MTU size set in the eth-config.